# Not getting date from option value

Tags: jquery

I need to display the date from an `option` in an alert box.

HTML:

```
<select id="account_type" name="account_type">
  <option value="1">Thursday May 29 at 2:00 PM ET</option>
  <option value="2">Tuesday May 22 at 10:00 AM ET</option>
</select>

<input type="image" id="submit" src="http://image.iloqal.com/lib/fe5c1570746107757c1c/m/1/55599_submit_btn.jpg"  alt="Submit">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click({
    var str = $(this).find('#account_type option:selected').text();
    var d = new Date(str);
    var n = d.getDay() + "" + d.getMonth() + "" + d.getHour();
    alert("your Date is ", n);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your event handler:

```
$("#submit").click({
  var str = $(this).find('#account_type option:selected').text();
```

You are searching for the option underneath `this` - but `this` is the element on which the event was triggered. In your case, it's the submit button. The `select` box is not a child of the button, therefore the call to `find` will not return anything.

Since the select box has an ID, and DOM IDs are unique, you do not need to restrict your search at all, and

```
$("#submit").click({
  var str = $('#account_type option:selected').text();
```

will suffice.

Comment: yes  you r right but i need to show alert for particular day and month From EST date format what else I have to do

Comment: That sounds like a different question to me - if you want to know how to convert date formats, there are already plenty of answers here on SO. If they don't solve your particular problem, please create a new question specific to that.

Comment: ok suppose i don't want to convert whatever value i am getting from option  value i need to retrieve just month and date for which  i used d.getDay() and d.getMonth() it is very simple eg but i am unable to figure out what is wrong on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this........

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $("#submit").click({

         var str=$('#account_type option:selected').text();
         var d= new Date(str);
         var n=d.getDay()+""+d.getMonth()+""+d.getHour();
         alert("your Date is ",n);
         });
```

Comment: it should be `d.getHours();` not `d.getHour()`

Comment: it is selecting date from option but not showing alert of particular day and month and hour

Answer (score 0):

this code works

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#submit").click(function(){

     var str=$('#account_type option:selected').text();
     alert("str : "+str);
     var d= new Date(str);
     var n=d.getDay()+""+d.getMonth()+""+d.getHours();
     alert("your Date is ",n);
     });
    });
```

for getting the text inside

After, this line

```
var d= new Date(str);
```

doesn't really make sense, read about the Date class documentation